# New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMemberInfo]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I need to run this cmdlet `$uaRoleMemberInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMemberInfo` .

I successfully connect to AzureAD using cmdlet `Connect-AzureAD` and I am able to run it on one pc but on other I get an error:

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMemberInfo]: verify that the assembly containing 
this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:21
+ ... emberInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMem ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

p.s AzureAD module is installed
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need to install and import the `AzureAD` module

Comment: This module is imported :), without it I wouldn't be able to run "Connect-AzureAD"

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Sorry, it sounded like you were using `Connect-AzureAD` only on the first machine (where it works as expected). Any difference in module version or similar between the two machines?

Comment: It's similar.. I tried to install AzureADPreview module because it was missing on the first machine but it didn't help :( @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: What do you mean "missing on the first machine" - I thought you said both commands were working just fine on the first machine?

Comment: Okay I fixed it.. Seems that AzureADPreview module should be imported in that way: `Install-Module AzureADPreview -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber` `Import-Module AzureADPreview -Force`

Comment: Sweet, you should post an answer to your own question! :)

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the `[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RoleMemberInfo]` type, the `AzureADPreview` module needs to be installed and imported.

It can be done in this way:

```bsh
Install-Module AzureADPreview -Scope CurrentUser -Force -AllowClobber
Import-Module AzureADPreview -Force
```

Comment: Yuck.  It's called "preview" which means M$ is some day going to change the name of the module and we'll have to edit all our code.